# Unit tests fail when tests run as set?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, gradle, junit

[Link to repo](https://github.com/kbajpai/algo)

I'm **learning** Java Unit Testing, and wrote some Unit Tests for some algorithms.

When I run the Unit Tests **individually**, they pass fine, but when I run them **as a set**, only the first one passes and rest of them fails.

For example, Test1, Test2, and Test3 are run as a set; then Test1 passes, and Test2 and Test3 fail.

If I comment out code for Test1, and run Test2, and Test3; Test2 passes and Test3 fails.

When I run them individually, they all pass.

**Code for the Algorithm**:

```
package com.kbajpai.algorithms.ds;

class Node {
    private static Node sInstance;

    static {
        try {
            sInstance = new Node();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not create singleton instance");
        }
    }

    static Node getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    private long mData;
    private int mCount;
    private Node mLeft;
    private Node mRight;

    private Node() {
        mCount = 0;
        mLeft = null;
        mRight = null;
    }

    private Node(long data) {
        mData = data;
        mLeft = null;
        mRight = null;
        mCount = 1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (mCount == 0) {
            return "";
        } else {
            if (mLeft != null) {
                sb.append(mLeft.toString()).append(",");
            }
            sb.append(mData).append(":").append(mCount);
            if (mRight != null) {
                sb.append(",").append(mRight.toString());
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void insert(long data) {
        if (mCount == 0) {
            mData = data;
            mCount++;
        } else {
            if (data == mData) {
                mCount++;
            } else if (data > mData) {
                if (mRight != null) {
                    mRight.insert(data);
                } else {
                    mRight = new Node(data);
                }
            } else {
                if (mLeft != null) {
                    mLeft.insert(data);
                } else {
                    mLeft = new Node(data);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    String getScores(long[] data) {
        for (long aData : data) {
            insert(aData);
        }

        return toString();
    }
}
```

**Code for UnitTests:**

```
package com.kbajpai.algorithms.ds;

import com.kbajpai.datagen.ds.ScoreStatsData;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class NodeTest {
    @Test
    public void test01ScoreStats_Ten() throws Exception {
        long[] data = ScoreStatsData.getInstance().getNumbers(ScoreStatsData.FILE_TEN);
        String expected = ScoreStatsData.getInstance().getStats(ScoreStatsData.FILE_TEN_STATS);

        assertTrue(expected.equals(Node.getInstance().getScores(data)));
    }

    @Test
    public void test02ScoreStats_Hundred() throws Exception {
        long[] data = ScoreStatsData.getInstance().getNumbers(ScoreStatsData.FILE_HUNDRED);
        String expected = ScoreStatsData.getInstance().getStats(ScoreStatsData.FILE_HUNDRED_STATS);

        String actual = Node.getInstance().getScores(data);
        assertTrue(expected.equals(actual));
    }

    @Test
    public void test03ScoreStats_Thousand() throws Exception {
        long[] data = ScoreStatsData.getInstance().getNumbers(ScoreStatsData.FILE_THOUSAND);
        String expected = ScoreStatsData.getInstance().getStats(ScoreStatsData.FILE_THOUSAND_STATS);

        String actual = Node.getInstance().getScores(data);
        assertTrue(expected.equals(actual));
    }

    @Test
    public void test04ScoreStats_Million() throws Exception {
        long[] data = ScoreStatsData.getInstance().getNumbers(ScoreStatsData.FILE_MILLION);
        String expected = ScoreStatsData.getInstance().getStats(ScoreStatsData.FILE_MILLION_STATS);

        String actual = Node.getInstance().getScores(data);
        assertTrue(expected.equals(actual));
    }

    @Test
    public void test05ScoreStats_TenMillion() throws Exception {
        long[] data = ScoreStatsData.getInstance().getNumbers(ScoreStatsData.FILE_TEN_MILLION);
        String expected = ScoreStatsData.getInstance().getStats(ScoreStatsData.FILE_TEN_MILLION_STATS);

        String actual = Node.getInstance().getScores(data);
        assertTrue(expected.equals(actual));
    }
}
```

N.B:

- Using **Gradle** with **IntelliJ IDEA**
- [Link to repo](https://github.com/kbajpai/algo)

Comment: It's probably because you're using singletons all over the place.
Since `Node` is a Singleton you don't create a new one in every test case, but use the same one from the previous test again and that contains all the entries you added before of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by your use of `static` variables with persistent state. The first test runs, it puts some data in the singleton object(s), and that data is still there when the second and later tests run in the same batch.

To fix this, you will need to either reset the singletons between each test or rewrite your code to not use the singleton pattern in the first place.

Comment: Changed the **Node** from singleton to non-singleton. I was suspecting that on **ScoreStatsData**, never thought about Node.

Comment: how did you identify the singleton? How could you remove it?

Comment: oh, [is it the private constructors?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Java)

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer It's the `static` instance, and everything using it. Private constructors are part of the singleton pattern, but they're just to _force_ everything to use the `static` instance.